# Mocking method in production code, not in tests

Tags: python, mocking

I have a method in my code like this :

```
def save(items):
   try:
       for item in items():
          do_something(item)
   except Exception:
      my_logging.warning("error happened")

def do_something(item):
   pass
```

I would like to invoke this method from another location in the code, however, I would like to call a different method instead of `do_something(item)` :

```
@transaction.atomic
def do_with_transaction(item)
   delete(item)
   do_something(item)
```

Is it ok to use mock with side effect for production code? this way I can mock `do_something()` to use `do_with_transaction(item)`.
It looks to me like a clean solution.

Comment: Would that not be a really bad practice and design decision to do such a thing?

Comment: this is what  I am trying to find out..

Comment: It would be. Your code should be easy to read and doing something like this (especially in production source) sounds like you're going to confuse every future reader/maintainer of the code, but this is just my 2 cents

Comment: "Is it ok to use mock with side effect for production code?" : no, definitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is to reuse `save(items)` but calling another function (instead of `do_something()` in the `for` loop, just pass the desired function as argument:

```
def save(items, callback=do_something):
   for item in items():
       try:
          callback(item)
       except Exception as e:
          my_logging.exception("error %s happened on item %s", e, item)
```

and then:

```
save(items, do_something_with_transaction)
```